# Want to implement working of Refresh(F5,Ctrl+F5) through programming(PHP)

Tags: php, ajax, post, refresh

I had made an ajax call to google.com and search for my content in every row..using simple_html_dom.php library. there may be a case wen i got my result in first page and displays it. Now the problem is that if i didint found my content on 1,2,3,4....20(is the last limit set by me).But my function keeps on fetching data as i had set set_time_limit(0).But i cant wait long(say 90sec)..and if i set to 90..it may be possible that my content is being fetched(behind code).

BUT BUT BUT...if i refresh my page after a long time(say 55sec) i atonce or in 4,5sec i got my result. So how can i re-post my request with same data..if execution time(set to a specific limit) crosses this limit. Hope u undrstand my problem...

Editing made:[By aakash sahai]
suppose if execution is in progress at 55sec and i let it to continue it may result in either error or it keeps on executing say 100sec..
but if at 55sec i pressed refreshed the page..the post is again made(as shown in Firebug Console) and i get result in 5sec..means total 60 sec(with refresh) and 100sec(without refresh)

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to restart the PHP process/request every 55 seconds?

If your host is a *nix compatible one, I would set up a cron job to execute the PHP script every 55 seconds.

Comment: i m a beginner in php and dont know that much :(